# Set up a Hash for Integers?

Tags: c++

I have to create a hash for a set of ints. The hash function which I need to use is this:

```
f(x) = k * x % TableSize.
```

I know I definitely need 4 loops, with them being set up like this:

```
Outer loop - TableSize = 10 to 1000
Middle loop - k = 1 to 500
Inner loop - create a table, and set it to -1
Inner inner loop - step through 10 #s loc = f(num)
```

The problem is, while I kind of know how to set up the outer and middle loops, I'm stuck regarding the last two loops.

While I know how to set up a hash table when it comes to strings, I don't know how to do it for ints (as I heard that the setup is a bit different). Also, based on the requirements, would I be creating the table in the inner loop, or just calling a different function?

This is everything which I have in my .h file.

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class intHash{

public:
intHash(int tableSize);
~intHash();

void someStuff(){
    for (int TableSize = 10; TableSize < 1000; TableSize++){ 
        for (int k = 1; k < 500; k++){
            for (){
                intHash(-1);
                for (){

                }
            }
        }
    }
}


private:
string *hashTable;
};
```

Comment: I would wonder what all the requirements are - especially how do you handle has collisions (lists per entry or skipping to new entry in fixed table size with a sentinel value in table or separate bool per entry for in use).  Depending on this, hashing will be quite different.  Because you have a single pointer to a "string", it leads be to believe you are not using lists, but that is just a guess.  Also, that string should probably be an int for integers, a template parameter, or the whole thing a std::unordered_map overall.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this was kinda fun to do.  Of course, you turn this in as-is and you will fail your assignment for cheating big time.

This hash is using a boolean value to determine if the hash is in use or not.  It handles collisions by stepping through the table by one until an opening is found.  The other method is to set a list at each location and walk the list with compares.  Either works.

Notice that all you need to do to use another type is change the `HashValueTableEntry` value's type.  The type needs to support some arithmetic to use as is, but I would expect a new hash function for more complex types.

Anyway, this gives you a working idea of a hash function.

```
#include <iostream>

class intHash
{
public:
    typedef int HashValueType;

    intHash(int tableSize)
    {
        m_tableSize = tableSize;
        m_hashTable = new HashValueTableEntry[tableSize];
    }

    ~intHash()
    {
        delete[] m_hashTable;
    }

    HashValueType add(int value)
    {
        int hashValue = hash(value);
        m_hashTable[hashValue].inUse = true;
        m_hashTable[hashValue].value = value;

        return hashValue;
    }

    bool get(HashValueType hashValue, int *value)
    {
        if(m_hashTable[hashValue].inUse)
        {
            *value = m_hashTable[hashValue].value;
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    void remove(HashValueType hashvalue)
    {
        m_hashTable[hashvalue].inUse = false;
    }

private:
    struct HashValueTableEntry
    {
        HashValueTableEntry() : value(0), inUse(false) {}
        int value;
        bool inUse;
    };

    int hash(int value)
    {
        static const int k = 7;
        int currentHash = (value * k ) % m_tableSize;

        int overflowCounter = 0;

        // Collision resolution
        while(m_hashTable[currentHash].inUse == true && 
              m_hashTable[currentHash].value != value)
        {
            currentHash++;
            if(overflowCounter++ == m_tableSize)
            {
                // assert, end the world, error whatever.
                // At this point though, currentHash is garbage and should be handled.
                break;
            }
        }

        return currentHash;
    }

    HashValueTableEntry *m_hashTable;
    int m_tableSize;
};

int main(void)
{
    intHash hash(100);
    int hashValues[100];

    for(int i=0; i<10; i++)
    {
        hashValues[i] = hash.add(i);

        // Purposely setup hash collisions to show that it is handled.
        hashValues[i+10] = hash.add(i+100);
    }

    for(int i=0; i<20; i++)
    {
        int tableValue = 0;
        hash.get(hashValues[i], &tableValue);
        std::cout << "Hash is " << hashValues[i] << " value is " << tableValue << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```